# How to solve a matrix equation (matrix = 0) with Sympy?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, equation

How do I solve a system of equations with Sympy if the system is written as the X matrix?

I have this code

```
from sympy import *
x1, x2 = symbols('x1 x2') 
u1 = 0.0005 u2 = 0.0005
K = sqrt(2)*10^-3
A = 0.2
X = Matrix([40*u1/(A*x2) + 10*u2/(A*x2) - (x1*K*sqrt(x2))/(A*x2), u1/A + u2/A - K*sqrt(x2)/A])
```

The X is a matrix, as you can see. I need to find the values for x1 and x2 when the X matrix = 0. I'm going to linearize this matrix.

Yes. I want the X matrix to be on this form. Not Ax = b form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
solve(X)
```

returns `[{x1: 25.0000000000000, x2: 0.500000000000000}]`

Equating to 0 is implicitly understood in `solve`, if you pass it a bunch of symbolic expressions.

Note that your system is **not** linear: there is division by x2 and square root of x2.